# MEF: Find type of lazy import

Tags: mef

I used InheritedExport attribute, and have a tree of objects. Think IMessageSender where I have SmtpSender, TextSender, HttpPostSender. But through decorator pattern I have additional classes that also inherit this MEF InheritedExport attribute.

However when composing the senders, I do not want to decorators to be composed.
Now Lazy could help, whereas I only retrieve the objects that are not of the Decorator type. But I can't ask Lazy what T actually is. Perhaps metadata could help, but the metadata only applies to the object that has this metadata. I don't want to force implementers (read: developers) to add the correct metadata to their decorator or sender.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do something similar.  In the end I opted to add metadata that gave me the required information, but I can see why that's not ideal for your.

One other possibility would be to switch from using an automatic import via attributes, and explicitly call [CompositionService.GetExports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833158.aspx) instead.  Then you'd end up with an `IEnumerable` of [Export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.export.aspx) objects.  This would let you get at the contract name (usually, but not always, the type name) and the contract metadata.  I *think* that the contract metadata always includes the type name, so you'd have the information you're looking for.

Comment: Only now did I figure out what you meant with metadata! :)
So the answer could be a bit more specific, but it is actually correct! :)

Comment: Just re-read my answer and even I can barely understand what I meant.  Sorry!  Anyway, if you've moved to .NET 4.5, try looking at the new RegistrationBuilder API.  You might be able to use it instead of `InheritedExportAttribute` to programmatically control which types get composed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, to get the type of a Lazy member:

```
.GetType().GetProperty("Value").PropertyType
```

Comment: This only returns the base class and I can't find out which subclass it actually is.